# Не открывается сохранённый файл index.html

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, кодировка

Win 7, IDLE (Python 3.8 32-bit)
Не открывается сохранённый файл index.html
Код скрипта:

```
# coding: utf8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    file = open('index.html', mode='r', encoding='CP1251')
    print(file) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='index.html' mode='r' encoding='CP1251'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это не ошибка, а текстовое представление объекта `_io.TextIOWrapper`, с помощью которого будет осуществляться работа с файлом.

Для получения содержимого файла вызывайте метод `read()`:

```
    ...
    print(file)
    
    text = file.read()
    print(text)
```

Comment: Уважаемый gil9red. Спасибо. Сделал по Вашему. Опять ошибка: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='index.html' mode='r' encoding='CP1251'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\6\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Александр\Desktop\6\main.py", line 8, in main
    text = file.read()
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 17426: character maps to <undefined>
>>>

Comment: @user425641, значит тот файл не в cp1251 закодирован. Попробуйте открыть его с `utf-8`: `file = open('index.html', mode='r', encoding='utf-8')`. Но вообще, BeautifulSoup умеет работать напрямую с байтами и с файловыми объектами. Т.е. можно так: `soup = BeautifulSoup(file, "html.parser")`, а `file` будет работать с байтами (в этом случае не нужно кодировку указывать): `file = open('index.html', mode='rb')`. Или считать байты из файла и отдать `file = open('index.html', mode='rb')` `data = file.read()` `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")`

Comment: Делаю так: file = open('index.html', mode='rb') data = file.read() soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser") --- получаю ответ:  <_io.BufferedReader name='index.html'>

Comment: А не нужно выводить `print(file)`. Это ведь объект файла, а не его содержимое. Попробуйте: `print(data)` и/или `print(soup)`

Comment: print(soup) --- так открылся но в папке он пустой

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку. Ваш форум лучший !

Comment: @user425641, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)